# Is Renly's Rainbow Guard an overt gay reference?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I was reading the [ASOFAI wiki,](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rainbow_Guard) and saw that Renly's Kingsguard is called the Rainbow Guard in the books.

I can't see how this isn't a gay reference. The wikipage says that GRRM denies that it is, is there any evidence either way?

Comment: I thought this too when I read the books. Then I started noticing all the other hints that Renly was gay. But I believe GRRM when he says it was unintentional; given that he's never shied from controversy, he has no reason to deny this reference. Also, as HorusKol says, the symbolism does have a place in Westerosi society.

Answer (score 15):

[Wired](http://www.wired.com/2012/04/game-of-thrones-drowning/) points out the logic of the Rainbow Guard within the books, and the reason it isn't used/name in the show:

> A Rainbow Guard makes a certain amount of sense within the context of Westerosi society, whose dominant religion uses the rainbow to symbolize the seven aspects of God, but a Rainbow Guard strikes many readers as a distracting, fourth-wall-breaking gag about Renly’s sexuality.

Add also that the Rainbow Guard was created to contrast with the white-garbed Kingsguard.

While I can't directly confirm the source, this [report from a convention](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/To_Be_Continued_Chicago_IL_May_6_8) seems to support the wiki claims:

> The Rainbow Guard isn't meant to symbolize Renly's sexuality. It was more of a culmination of several unrelated things, such as the fact that he'd already used white for the Kingsguard and black for the Night's Watch. A rainbow is seven colors combined together in one object - he compared it to a shamrock being a Irish Catholic symbol of the Holy Trinity, three parts which make up one thing. Plus it has seven colors and is tied to the Seven, plus worshipers of the Seven use prism rainbows in their temples.

Martin has stated that the implied relationship between Renly and Loras was intentional  - so it would be surprising if he then choose to deny intentionally making a further implication with the use of Rainbow Guard.

> George specifically stated "Yes, I did intend those characters to be gay." Not that we didn't already know that of course, but I don't believe it's ever been actually confirmed before.

Comment: And the [LGBT rainbow flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag#LGBT_.28Lesbian.2C_Gay.2C_Bisexual.2C_Transgender.29_Pride_.281978.29) has only 6 colors.

Comment: Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar. It's not just GRRM, Terry Pratchett is on record as saying fans have found puns and references  in his books which he never intended to put in.

Comment: Even Tolkien - who could not abide allegory, and countless others, I imagine. I remember a story about a lecturer claiming an author has no right to the interpretation of their own work.

Comment: @HorusKol: I believe that's actually a fairly common view among postmodernists; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_the_Author and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfTheAuthor for some background. (The latter includes the story you're probably referring to. The author in question was Asimov.)

Answer (score -4):

Renly is not portrayed as gay in the books as opposed to his portrayal in the tv series. If I remember correctly, he named his kingsguard as the rainbow guard because he was bored of how colorless and dull the original kingsguard was.

According to http://awoiaf.westeros.org/

The rainbow guard wear different colored cloaks to connect them with the Faith of the Seven.

"Author George R. R. Martin did not intend the book's use of "Rainbow Guard" as a play on gay rights; however, HBO has elected not to use the "Rainbow Guard" in its adaptation due to the political connotations, despite the explicit depiction of the relationship between Renly Baratheon and Loras Tyrell."

Comment: "Author George R. R. Martin did not intend the book's use of "Rainbow Guard" This is what I'm asking about. There doesn't appear to be a reference on the wiki explaining where this comes from.

Comment: @BJATZ it isn't laid out explicitly - but Martin has been rather open about his intentions and hints with regards to Renly and Loras.

Comment: The rainbow guard might not be a gay reference, but Renly was unmistakably gay in the books.

Comment: To back up @SomeGuy, read the third paragraph under Appearence and Character http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Renly_Baratheon#Appearance_and_Character